# How to get Data From Mysql in Chunks

Tags: python, mysql, database

I Have a table in `Mysql` Which contains **10 Million** Entries so far, and I am writing a script in `python` in which I want to get data from DB in chunks of `100K`(**Number of row's**).

I have tried threw paging (https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/)
but unable to do it anyone can help me with this.

Comment: 100K number of records or 100K size data ?

Comment: @saintlyzero Hi Thanks i have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIMIT` in **MySQL**

`LIMIT` clause is used with the `SELECT`,`UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement to restrict the number of rows in the result set. 
It accepts one or two arguments which are `offset` and `count`.

**Syntax**

```sql
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
LIMIT offset, count;
```

`offset` specifies which row to start retrieving data from
`count` specifies the number of rows returned from a result set

**Usage**

```sql
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
LIMIT 100, 50
```

Here, `100` specifies the offset, i.e the query will start retrieving data starting from the `100th` record. 
`50` specifies the number of records that will be returned after the `100th` record.

**Eg.**

In your case,
`count` will be `100k` and the `offset` will be the multiples of `100k` starting from `0`

```sql
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
LIMIT 0, 100000
```

Next query will be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
LIMIT 100000, 100000
```

And so on..

So in your `python` code, `count` value will be same i.e `100000` whereas the `offset` value will change from `0`, `100000`, `200000`, .. . `offset` value is essentially the multiples of `100000`

For further reference, have a look here [link1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause/) [link2](https://www.guru99.com/limit.html)